# why first click on link button doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

I have this linkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SaveAllItems" class="saveAll"
                OnClientClick="saveToGroups();return false;"  
                OnClick="saveToAll_Click" 
                Text="Save Items"   />
```

My first click on this button doesnt work and I dont know why.
I tried adding `return false;` to OnClick but nothing has changed.

saveToGroups- works in js
saveToAll_Click - works in cs

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `return false` from your OnClientClick event, since it will not post your page back and prevent the button click being fired for the first time.

Comment: the OnClientClick - no need postback
OnClick - need postback

Comment: You can use `return false;` in your javascript function.

Comment: Try using an `alert()` in your javascript - you can identify whether there's an issue with your function.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `false` to OnClientClick -- it prevents the postback.