# link button does not works for first time in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I have the link button and Onclick event I am redirecting the page from code behind. My code is as follows:

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="UserRoleLinkButton" runat="server"  OnClick="UserRoleLinkButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I have set the text of link button like this:

```
        string[] roleNames = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Page.User.Identity.Name);
         if (roleNames.Count() > 1)
         {
             UserRoleLinkButton.Visible = true;
             UserRoleLinkButton.Text = roleNames[1].ToString();
         }
```

and in code behind I am doing this

```
     protected void UserRoleLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (UserRoleLinkButton.Text == "SuperAdmin")
            {
                Response.Redirect(@"~/Admin/AdminHome.aspx");
            }
            else if (UserRoleLinkButton.Text == "YPAdmin")
            {
                Response.Redirect(@"~/Admin/YellowPages/NotificationMaster.aspx");
            }
            else if (UserRoleLinkButton.Text == "YPOperator")
            {
                Response.Redirect(@"~/Admin/YellowPages/ManageListing.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect(@"~/Account/MyProfile.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            BRMessengers.BRError(this, "Server Error");
            log.Fatal(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url + "   Message : " + ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

any thing wrong with this code?? If so where.In first click it shows 404 error(Page Not Found)

Note[When i click for second time it works fine]
I have tried from javascript as wel but the result is same. Here is my javascript code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $("#UserRoleLinkButton").live("click", function () {
            if ($('[id$=UserRoleLinkButton]').text() === "SuperAdmin") {
                alert('Test');
                window.location.pathname = "Admin/AdminHome.aspx";
            }
            else if ($('[id$=UserRoleLinkButton]').text() === "YPAdmin") {
                alert('Test1');
                window.location.pathname = "Admin/YellowPages/NotificationMaster.aspx";
            }
            else if ($('[id$=UserRoleLinkButton]').text() === "YPOperator") {
                alert('Test2');
                window.location.pathname = "Admin/YellowPages/ManageListing.aspx";
            }
            else {
                alert('Test3');
                window.location.pathname = "Account/MyProfile.aspx";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Any solution is surely appretiated.

I have seen this question for reference

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192209/why-first-click-on-link-button-doesnt-work)

Comment: how you set the text of your link button.

Comment: @Arunesh Can you post the code,that how did you pass the text value in codebehind

Comment: Is the code that sets the Text of the LinkButton inside a `if(!this.IsPostBack) {...}`?

Comment: no it is not setting in !IsPostBack